# Clicked button with selenimun/phantomJS/BeautifulSoup in nested iframe elements

Tags: selenium, iframe, phantomjs

This is a similar question to one that I asked previously, however, I am unable to wrap my head around why I can't get this to work. This is what the page looks like:

```
<body>

     <iframe src="src1URL">
       #document

          <iframe src="src2URL">
           #document

             <div class="clickable">

          </iframe>

     </iframe>

</body>
```

I want to click the play button that in nested deep in iframes. I am able to get my webdriver to switch to the 1st iframe element by doing:

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.get(url)
iframe_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="iframegame"]')  #xpath to 1st iframe
self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)
```

From here I can look and get element inside the 1st iframe, and able to pull out src2URL.

But i want to get elements inside the second iframe, so I tried this:

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.get(url)
iframe_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="iframegame"]')  #xpath to 1st iframe
self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)
iframe_element_inner = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="game_playercnt"]/iframe') #xpath to iframe 2
self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element_inner)
```

But iframe 2 does not seem to ever get run by the driver. I only end up with the raw page html for iframe 2, not a page DOM. So i can't select the button that I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: driver.switch_to.frame(0) switch to nested iframes after you switch to the outer iframes.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class='clickable']').click() after that.

Comment: tried that. did not work. just ended up with raw page html again

Comment: Have you got this work? If yes, could you please share it? Thanks